# PHP, Returning to a calling Page after saving a record in a Edit page

Tags: php, url

Lets say I have a Page with a List (`list.php`).

I click on a row on that list to Edit that record. I go to a edit.php Page.

I have 3 buttons on that edit.php page. Save, Apply, Cancel

1. Save button - Saves the Record and returns to the (`list.php`) Page
2. Apply button - Saves Record but stays on the same page (`edit.php`)
3. Cancel button - No save, just return to the (`list.php`) Page

But now image if I can access for edit that item on a different page. How do I return to that calling page?

- Do I add a parameter(code) to the URL? something like a Page Origination Code?
- Do I save the previous page URL in a session? (bad, they can right click open another page and that would be saved to session url)

Am just curious to how others return to a previous page after a SAVE.

Comment: The login Page is a good example, I seen some carry the returning URL as a parameter encoded. But i don't like the idea of it

Answer (score 1):

you can the server variable $_SERVER['HTTP_referrer'].
They are other ways also you can store in session the current page and use is processing page.

Comment: What happens if I get to the Edit Page with a right click open in new page.
and then go back to the the previous page on the other tab and start opening more pages with right click. When i return to the Edit Page what will be stored in $_SERVER['HTTP_referrer']? is is not like session?

Comment: This does indeed work, I just tried it. 

BUT

a quote from php.net php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
"The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted. "

Answer (score 1):

Adding a parameter to the URL is the only reliable though quote ugly way.

That's why such an in-place editions nowadays often being implemented using AJAX, and this very site is a perfect example.

However, there are different cases.
Login page is imperfect example for example, as you always have a form instead of just a link, and thus you can always store the current page in a hidden form field.

Another approach is possible if you are using some sort of front controller, and all requests actually being directed to the single index.php file which runs appropriate script based on the URI.

in this latter case you will need no more than mere a redirect to the current page.